# Python mock aggregate function of MongoDB in Pymongo

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pymongo

I want to mock `aggregate` function provided by `PyMongo` for below code:

```
client = MongoClient(host="localhost", port=27017,username="Harsha", password="Harsha", authSource="admin")
db_obj = client["DB name"]
mongo_result = db_obj[collection_name].aggregate(pipeline)
```

I want to mock `aggregate` function.

Can anyone please help me to mock the aggregate function?

I tried the following code snippet to mock the aggregate function:

**Trial 1:**

```
from pymongo import collection
collection_obj = collection.Collection(client["DB name"], "collection_name")

def mock_get(self, *args):
    return "Result I want"

@mock.patch(collection_obj.Collection.aggregate, side_effect=mock_get)
def test_demo(self):
    .
    .
    .
    .
```

This is not working as `@mock.patch` requires string full path argument.

So I also tried to give complete path of `aggregation` function

**Trial 2:**

```
class BasicTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def mock_get(self, *args):
        return "Result I want"

    @mock.patch('pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate', side_effect=mock_get)
    def test_demo(self):
        .
        .
        .
        .
```

This is giving me:

```
TypeError: test_demo() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

patch passes in the mocked object to the decorated function as an extra argument so you can do assertions on it. Change your code like this:

```
@mock.patch('pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate', side_effect=mock_get)
def test_demo(self, mock_object):
     .
     .
```

Comment: I still keep having errors when mocking aggregate with a Mongoengine model

Comment: @RyanAquino certainly you are getting a different error if you followed this advice, so maybe ask a new question.